# Set pages with a specific name in the URL to noindex

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

for a WordPress page I want to set all pages containing **/test/page/** to "noindex".

My attempt so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\/test\/page\/
RewriteRule .* - [E=MY_SET_HEADER:1]
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=MY_SET_HEADER
```

Unfortunately this does not work.
I guess the problem is my RegEx
Who can help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Header set X-Robots tag "noindex, follow" env=MY_SET_HEADER
> ```

It should be `X-Robots-Tag`, not `X-Robots tag`.

> ```
> RewriteRule .* - [E=MY_SET_HEADER:1].
> ```

You also have an erroneous dot at the end of your `RewriteRule` directive.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\/test\/page\/
> ```

The regex can be *simplified* but otherwise it still matches any URL *containing* `/test/page/`. Slashes do not need to be backslash escaped and the `.*` prefix is superfluous. ie. It's the same as simply `/test/page/`.

The mod_rewrite directives would also need to go *before* the existing WordPress directives. If you placed the rule at the end of your `.htaccess` file (after the WP front-controller) then the mod_rewrite directive will simply never be processed.

That should resolve your problem, however, your rule can be simplified. You don't need to use mod_rewrite here. You can use mod_setenvif to set your env var.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/test/page/" NOINDEX
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEX
```

By not using mod_rewrite the directives don't necessarily need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file.

---

### Using WordPress / Front-Controller

Since you are using WordPress and consequently rewriting the request through a front-controller (ie. `index.php`), you will need to check for the `REDIRECT_NOINDEX` env var instead.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/test/page/" NOINDEX
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEX
```

Whilst we set the `NOINDEX` env var, when the request is internally rewritten/redirected (by WordPress) the env var is renamed by prefixing `REDIRECT_`. So, `NOINDEX` becomes `REDIRCT_NOINDEX` after the first round of processing when the `Header` directive is processed (late).

Comment: Sorry - my text editor added (changed) the dot and the X-Robots tag.
Have corrected my post now.

Unfortunately this does not work with SetEnvIf

Comment: By "not work", you mean the `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header is not seen in the response? Or are you getting some other error?

Comment: Correct, I use the Chrome Extension Live http Headers

Comment: If you remove the `env=NOINDEX` argument is the header set? Try setting a different header, eg. `X-TEST` instead - does that get set?

Comment: I removed env=NOINDEX
Now all pages have in the header x-robots-tag: noindex, follow

Comment: No matter which page I call up - now all pages have the entry in the header - even those without page and test - any idea?

Comment: Yes, that was just a test. You need to prefix the env var with `REDIRECT_` in the `Header` directive. I've updated my answer. (Sorry, I overlooked you were using WordPress.)

Comment: Very good and well explained answer ++. @user11274144: Please mark it as accepted